# Consulta PHP Mysql com filtragem por vários critérios

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, amigos. Tenho um banco de dados de cadastros de membros de uma igreja. Fiz uma tabela para visualizar esses registros, mas como meu BD tem 39 colunas, peguei só as mais importantes, e no final da linha coloquei um link para o registro completo.

Nessa página inicial onde aparecem todos os registros, coloquei 7 selects (combobox) para fazer uma filtragem combinando situações.

Os selects são:

SITUAÇÃO | ESTADO CIVIL | SEXO | STATUS | FAIXA ETÁRIA | FORMA DE ADMISSAO | FORMA DE SAÍDA

Os selects não serão preenchidos dinamicamente. Os valores são fixos.

Quero que, ao entrar na página, o usuário receba a lista de todos os registros. E ao clicar, por exemplo, em situação (membro), sexo (M) e status(ausente), e receber os dados de todos os membros do sexo masculino que estão ausentes.

E outras combinações também.

Já consegui retornar o valor com todos os registros ao entrar na página, e essa parte está funcionando. . Os resultados aparecem corretamente na tabela.

Então acrescentei os selects, já populados, e o botão.

E é agora é que preciso de ajuda: Como monto a query para que, ao clicar no botão, ele observe os critérios selecionados? Sendo que, se algum select estiver em branco, ele deve retornar todos os registros, mas se estiver marcado, retornar apenas aqueles correspondentes. Se alguém puder dar uma força...

Abaixo segue meu código completo:

````
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

  if (!isset($_SESSION['UsuarioID'])) {

      session_destroy();
      header("Location: login.html"); exit;
  }


include("classe/conecta.php");

$consulta = "SELECT Cod,Nome,Tel,Cel,Email,DtNasc,Status FROM CadPessoas order by Nome";
$con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body><center>
       <br><br>
       
       
            <p>
            <table  bgcolor="azure" border=0 cellpadding="10">
                <tr>
                    <td width="130px">Situação<br>
                    <select style=" width:130px" name="situacao">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Membros">Membros</option>
                    <option value="nao_membros">Solteiros</option>
                </select></td>
                    <td width="130px">Estado Civil<br>
                    <select style=" width:130px" name="estcivil">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="solteiros">Solteiros</option>
                    <option value="casados">Casados</option>
                    <option value="separados">Separados</option>
                    <option value="divorciados">Divorciados</option>
                    <option value="viuvos">Viúvos</option>
                </select></td>
                    <td width="130px">Sexo<br>
                    <select style=" width:130px" name="sexo">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="m">Masculino</option>
                    <option value="f">Feminino</option>
                </select></td>
                    <td width="130px">Status<br>
                    <select style=" width:130px" name="status">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="ativos">Ativos</option>
                    <option value="inativos">Inativos</option>
                    <option value="impossibilitados">Impossibilitados</option>
                    <option value="ausentes">Ausentes</option>
                    <option value="sob_disciplina">Sob Disciplina</option>
                </select></td>
                    <td width="130px">Faixa Etária<br>
                    <select style=" width:130px" name="faixaetaria">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="criancas">Até 08 Anos</option>
                    <option value="juniores">09 a 11 Anos</option>
                    <option value="adolescentes">12 a 17 Anos</option>
                    <option value="Jovens1">18 a 25 Anos</option>
                    <option value="Jovens2">26 a 35 Anos</option>
                    <option value="Adultos1">36 a 49 Anos</option>
                    <option value="Adultos2">50 a 59 Anos</option>
                    <option value="Idosos1">60 a 64 Anos</option>
                    <option value="Idosos2">65 a 79 Anos</option>
                    <option value="Idosos3">80 acima</option>
                </select>
                    <td width="130px">Forma de Admissão<br>
                    <select style=" width:130px" name="admissao">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="batismo">Batismo</option>
                    <option value="transferencia">Transferência</option>
                    <option value="reconciliacao">Reconciliação</option>
                    <option value="aclamacao">Aclamação</option>
                </select></td>
                    <td width="130px">Forma de Saída<br>
                    <select style=" width:130px" name="saida">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="transferencia">Transferência</option>
                    <option value="falecimento">Falecimento</option>
                    <option value="desligamento">Desligamento</option>
                </select></td>
                <td width="130px"><br><input type="submit" name="botaobuscar" value="PESQUISAR" style=" width:130px"  /></td>
                </tr></table>

            </p>
        </form>
</form>



       <br><br>
       
       <table border=0>
           <tr bgcolor="blue" align="center" <div style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; color: white;">
               <td>Código:</td>
               <td>Nome:</td>
               <td>Telefone:</td>
               <td>Celular:</td>
               <td>E-mail:</td>
               <td>Data de Nascimento:</td>
               <td>Status:</td>
                <td>Ação</td>
           </tr>
           <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
           <tr style="cursor:default" onMouseOver="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor='#B0E0E6'" onMouseOut="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor=''">
               <td><?php echo $dado["Cod"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $dado["Nome"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $dado["Tel"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $dado["Cel"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $dado["Email"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dado["DtNasc"])); ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $dado["Status"]; ?></td>
               <td><a href="dadoscompletos.php?codigo=<?php echo $dado["Cod"]; ?>">Dados Completos</a>
               </td>
           </tr>
           <?php } ?>
           
       </table>
        </center>  
    </body>
    
</html> ```
````

Answer (score -1):

Não existe uma resposta só para isso, o que eu faria é o seguinte:

Em cada select coloque uma opção chamada "Ignorar" como default

Faça uma query com o começo da consulta assim

```php
$query = "SELECT Cod,Nome,Tel,Cel,Email,DtNasc,Status FROM CadPessoas where ";
```

depois você teste para ver se veio como ignorar ou não e vai completando a query, assim:

```php
if ($sexo != "Ignorar"){

$query .= " sexo = $sexo and"; 

}
```

Repita isso com cada critério e no final coloque

```php
$query.= " order by nome";
```

Depois repare que a query vai ficar com o final `and order by nome` então você tem que usar replace para subatituir and order por apenas order.

Não esquenta com a negativação da pergunta, a pergunta está ok, o que não está ok é o ego destes caras que acham que a pergunta não está a altura do seu ego inflamado.

Espeto ter te dado a direção.

Comment: Acho que entendi o princípio, mas como eu faço para que o valor selecionado no combobox preencha a variável na query quando eu clicar no botão?

Comment: AI, você vai submeter o formulário e pegar os dados dele com $_POST do outro lado. Da uma estudada no método post.